# make grouping of list of objects on basis of path matching

Tags: python, python-3.x

hi I have this kind of data

```
data = [{'name': 'root/folder1/asd/file1.csv'},'last_modified': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 15, 11, 45, 47),
        {'name': 'root/folder1/asd/file2.csv' , 'last_modified': datetime.datetime(2025, 8, 15, 11, 45, 47),}, 
        {'name': 'root/folder1/folder2/folder3/new.csv', 'last_modified': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 15, 11, 45, 47)}, 
        {'name': 'root/folder1/folder2/folder3/new.csv','last_modified': datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 15, 11, 45, 47)}]
```

now I want to get file from this data which have same path until file name and have latest last_modified date. and count of files with same path as showed in below

**Expected result :**

```
data = [{'name': 'root/folder1/asd/file2.csv' , 'last_modified': datetime.datetime(2025, 8, 15, 11, 45, 47) , 'count':2},{'name': 'root/folder1/folder2/folder3/new.csv','last_modified': datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 15, 11, 45, 47), 'count':2}]
```

as  `root/folder1/bsd`  was same path for both files and  last_modified of this file2 was latest one and count is 2 as total 2 files found with this duplication. and same in 2nd record  `root/folder1/folder2/folder3` same path and  last_modified was latest and count is 2 as total 2 files found with this duplication.  If there is no match then one 1 existing file will considered as latest.

**Tried till now**

```
sorted_files = sorted(data, key=lambda d: (d.get('last_modified', {})), reverse=True)
```

which is sorting files but not sure how to remove non latest ones and keep records which are only singles and add count to it

Comment: Your `}` is in the wrong place on the first row of `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary whose keys are the directory names. Then when updating the dictionary, you can check if the current `last_modified` is greater than the previous one for that directory.

```
data_dict = {}
for item in data:
    dir = os.path.dirname(item['name'])
    if dir not in data_dict:
        item['count'] = 1
        data_dict[dir] = item
    else:
        count = data_dic[dir]['count'] + 1
        if item['last_modified'] > data_dict[dir]['last_modified']:
            data_dict[dir] = item
        data_dic[dir]['count'] = count

result = list(data_dict.values())
```

Comment: thanks for answer . just one thing is missing which is count . can you please tell about that as well?

Comment: I've added the code for counting

Comment: thanks @Barmar sir you saved me so many times.  can you please suggest any good book or resource to learn these kind of complex problems ? thanks in advance

Comment: No, sorry. You just have to think about it logically.